# AnythingSlider and Changing the tab names?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

I am very new to all this. I am trying to do the following:
1) implement this in a way that users can change the content without coding
2) run in on a SP 2010 website
3) Currently, I have a HTML page in a page viewer and all relative files in a folder on the root web.

I need to know the best way to do this, but also how to change the tab names on the content slider?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kat and welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask here since you have multiple questions. I would recommend you split this question into multiple, more specific parts because it isn't clear what you mean by "implement this in a way that users can change the content without coding".

Anyway, I'll try and answer your question about AnythingSlider. What I'm guessing is that you want to change the text of the slider tab? Check out the [`navigationFormatter` option](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Navigation-options#wiki-navigationformatter) documentation on how to use it. If you get stuck or need additional help, just add a comment here.